# Как создать новый массив с информацией из другого

Tags: javascript

Есть три разных объекта books, genres и authors,

```
const books = {
  items: [
    {
      author_ids: [1, 2],
      genre_id: 1,
      id: 1,
      name: "testbook1",
      year: 1,
    },
    {
      author_ids: [2],
      genre_id: 2,
      id: 3,
      name: "testbook2",
      year: 5,
    },
    {
      author_ids: [2],
      genre_id: 3,
      id: 4,
      name: "testbook3",
      year: 10,
    },
  ],
};
const genres = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Рассказы",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Фантастика",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Мемуары",
    },
  ],
};

const authors = {
  items: [
    {
      first_name: "Александр",
      id: 1,
      last_name: "Пушкин",
      patronymic: "Сергеевич",
    },
    {
      first_name: "OleG",
      id: 2,
      last_name: "OlegoviCh",
      patronymic: "OlegoV",
    },
  ],
};
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы создавался новый массив newBooks, с новым свойством genre и authors, измененным в соотвествии с другими массивоми. Я так понимаю мне надо использовать array.filter или array.map, но не могу придумать функцию, которая будет создавать нужный мне массив.

Совмещая с ответом снизу

```js
let newBooks = {
  items: books.items.map((book) => ({
    ...book,
    genre: genres.items.filter((g) => g.id === book.genre_id
    ),
    author: authors.items.filter((author) => author.id === book.author_ids)
  })),
};

console.log(newBooks);
```

Но author возвращает пустой массив, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

если взять за основу ваши объекты.

```
let newBooks = { items: books.items.map(book => ({...book, genre: genres.items.filter(g=>g.id === book.genre_id)}))};

console.log(newBooks);
```

По факту используются обе предложенные вами функции. Но конечно можно обойтись и без них вовсе. Используя циклы и прочие возможности.

Ps Извините если что набираю с телефона

Comment: А как можно аналогичную ситуацию провернуть с авторами, если учитывать, что это массив, а не просто number?